# Spoofed Tunnel Route

Tags: traceroute, icmp

What does it mean when tracert always shows a single long jump?
The route below is always the same except the last hop goes
directly to any destination IP address that I choose.

And, how does the second-to-last point spoof this?  Is the
202.151.252.202 router/firewall increasing the ICMP TTL to
accomplish this?

```
>>> tracert 198.7.59.119

Tracing route to ping-test.net [198.7.59.119]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     3 ms     2 ms     3 ms  4GRouter.com [192.168.1.1]
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  3    72 ms    29 ms    24 ms  10.214.147.54
  4     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  5    58 ms    22 ms    25 ms  10.214.148.169
  6    33 ms    28 ms    31 ms  10.214.147.218
  7    24 ms    27 ms    29 ms  202.151.252.202
  8   278 ms   273 ms   267 ms  ping-test.net [198.7.59.119]

Trace complete.
```